# Display Faltlist after clicking on RadioButton React native

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a react native project , I want to display a flatlist after clicking on the RadioButton , Actually I have two RadioButtons

This is the two Flatlist that I've created (I have test them ,they work )

```
const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([
{Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: 'Wed 9:00', FinishDate: 'Wed 17:00'},
{Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: 'Thu 9:00', FinishDate: 'Thu 17:00'},
{Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: 'Fri 9:00', FinishDate: 'Fri 17:00'},
{Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: 'Sat 9:00', FinishDate: 'Sat 17:00'},
{Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: 'Sun 9:00', FinishDate: 'Sun 17:00'},
```

]);

```
const [scdatasource, scsetChecked] = useState([
    {Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: '27 Wed 9:00', FinishDate: '27 Wed 17:00'},
    {Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: '28 Thu 9:00', FinishDate: '28 Thu 17:00'},
    {Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: '29 Fri 9:00', FinishDate: '29 Fri 17:00'},
    {Site: 'CCTV (UK)  ', StartDate: '30 Sat 9:00', FinishDate: '30 Sat 17:00'},
  ]);
```

This is the function that I'll call it in the renderItem for both:

```
const ItemView = ({item, index}) => {
return (
  // a ScrollView to scroll the flatlist

  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{
      margin: 0,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      marginTop: 7,
      marginLeft: 5,
      paddingVertical: 7,
      paddingHorizontal: 0,
      backgroundColor: index % 2 === 0 ? '#FFFFFF' : '#eeeeee',
    }}>
    <Text
      style={{
        margin: 0,
        color: '#2a8495',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginLeft: 9,
      }}>
      {item.Site}
    </Text>
    <Text style={SecondScreenStyle.fieldtwo}>{item.StartDate}</Text>
    <Text style={SecondScreenStyle.fieldthree}>{item.FinishDate}</Text>
  </ScrollView>
);


 };
```

For the whole interface under the Header (ScheduledShiftsActivty)I've used PaperProvider:

```
return (
<PaperProvider>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Text style={SecondScreenStyle.title}>Shifts of this </Text>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 20}}>
      <RadioButton
        value="first"
        status={checked === 'first' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
        onPress={() => setChecked('first')}
        color="#F6982A"
      />
      <Text style={SecondScreenStyle.title}>week</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 80}}>
      <RadioButton
        value="second"
        status={checked === 'second' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
        onPress={() => setChecked('second')}
        color="#F6982A"
      />
      <Text style={SecondScreenStyle.title}>Month</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
  <View style={SecondScreenStyle.tableheader}>
    <Text style={{marginLeft: 8, color: '#FFFFFF', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
      Site
    </Text>

    <Text
      style={{
        margin: 0,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        marginLeft: 100,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      }}>
      Start Date
    </Text>
    <Text
      style={{
        margin: 0,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        marginLeft: 80,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      }}>
      Finish Date
    </Text>
  </View>
  
</PaperProvider>


 );
```

To call the Flalist (for example the first ) I should write :

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList
      data={scdatasource}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={ItemView}
      ListEmptyComponent={EmptyListMessage}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
```

I have created a function containg The SafeAreaView +setChecked , the setChecked worked but after clicking on the RadioButton nothing was shown

Comment: can you create expo snack with problem To be more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList
      data={checked === 'first' ? dataSource : scdatasource }
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={ItemView}
      ListEmptyComponent={EmptyListMessage}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simple. first, you have to key unique keys to both Flatlists. Here Is the minimal Example.

```
import React, {  useState, useContext } from 'react'
import {View, Text,Image, TouchableOpacity,StatusBar,PermissionsAndroid, ToastAndroid,FlatList} from 'react-native'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import { heightPercentageToDP as hp, widthPercentageToDP as wp,} from 'react-native-responsive-screen' 
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';

const whatsappstatsudownload = ({navigation}) =>{
    const [images , setImages] = useState([])
    const [videos , setVideo] = useState([])
    const [isimage, setIsimage ]  = useState(true)

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
      <View style={styles.flat_list_main_view_video}>
    </View>  
    );

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>    
          <StatusBar barStyle='dark-content' backgroundColor={"#00423a"}/>
            
            <View style ={styles.button_main_view}>  
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsimage(true)}
                  style={styles.main_linear_gradient}>
      

                    <TouchableOpacity 
                     onPress={() => setIsimage(true)}
                     style={[styles.text_icon_view,
                      {backgroundColor:isimage?'#236e64':'#fff'}]}>
                          <FontAwesome5 
                                style={{alignSelf:"center", marginLeft:wp(12)}}
                                name="download"
                                color={isimage?'#fff':'#236e64'}
                                size={16}
                            />  
                           <Text style={[styles.download_button_text,{color:isimage?'#fff':'#236e64'}]}>
                              Image
                           </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
              </TouchableOpacity>   

              
              
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsimage(false)}
                  style={styles.main_linear_gradient}>
                
                    <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => setIsimage(false)}   style={[styles.text_icon_view,
                    {backgroundColor:isimage?'#fff':'#236e64'}]}>
                      <FontAwesome5 
                          style={{alignSelf:"center", marginLeft:wp(12)}}
                          name="download"
                          color={ isimage?'#236e64':'#fff'}
                          size={16}
                      />  
                   <Text style={[styles.download_button_text,{color:isimage?'#236e64':'#fff'}]}>Video</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>  
              </TouchableOpacity> 

            </View>
           
            {isimage?
              <FlatList 
                initialNumToRender={10}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                horizontal={false}
                numColumns={2}
                contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent:"space-between", alignContent:"space-between"}}
                style={{alignSelf:'center'}}
                data={images}
                keyExtractor={(item) =>{return item.name }}
                 
                  renderItem={({item}) =>{                
                      return(
                        <View style={styles.flat_list_main_view_image}>
                        </View>  
                      )
                  }}
              /> 
            :
            <FlatList 
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, }}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                legacyImplementation={true}
              
                windowSize={50}
                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                initialNumToRender={5}
                updateCellsBatchingPeriod={30}
                getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({length: wp(35), offset: wp(35) * index, index})}
                maxToRenderPerBatch={7}
                numColumns={2}
                style={{alignSelf:'center'}}
                data={videos}
                keyExtractor={(item) =>{
                      return item.name
                }}
                renderItem={renderItem}
           /> 
         }
        </View>
    )
}

export default whatsappstatsudownload
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort ^^ , I've tried to add the line data={checked === 'first' ? dataSource : scdatasource } Like in the previous answer , your answer will surely help me Thank you ^^

Comment: you are most wlcm